# Displaying Geodata in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration

I have the following logstash filter configuration, wherein the input is a JSON file which already has latitude and longitude data. When I index the data, in the document, I do find attributes of longitude, and latitude. How can I use this information for displaying points on the map? When I go to the Visualize tab, and try to select from dropdown, it says that there is no compatible type. I understand that I need to make them as geohash type. Any ideas of how can I get it working?

```
filter{
json{
source => "message"
}
geoip {
source => "longitude"
target => "geoip"
add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
}
geoip {
source => "latitude"
target => "geoip"
add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ]
}
mutate {
convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]
}

}
output {
elasticsearch {
protocol => "http"
index => "my_business"
}
stdout { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the logstash template that gets automatically created, you can either rip the configuration of of there or simply name your index something like 'logstash-my_business' and it should add those fields for you automatically.